# automatically tracking time through start / stop progress

Tags: jira

I like to track time spent on JIRA issues when I click on `Start Progress` and then `Stop Progress`, or `Resolve`.

Is it possible to get JIRA to automatically allocate time to the task, like say:

- 14:20: Clicked on Start Progress
- 14:45: Clicked on Stop Progress > Logs 25 minutes to the task
- 15:30: Clicked on Start Progress
- 15:45: Clicked on Resolve > Logs 15 minutes to the task.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You might want to have a look at [Listeners](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Listeners):
"A Listener is a class that implements one of the Listener interfaces. It is then called whenever events occur in JIRA. Using those events, you can then perform any action you want."

In your case you could implement the [issueStarted](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/event/issue/IssueEventListener.html#issueStarted(com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent)), [issueStopped](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/event/issue/IssueEventListener.html#issueStopped(com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent)) and [issueResolved](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/event/issue/IssueEventListener.html#issueResolved(com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent)) method.
On issueStarted you could somehow save the current timestamp (e.g. in an invisible customfield) and on issueStopped/issueResolved you could trigger the creation of a worklog-entry.

Comment: I'm using AtlassianOnDemand.  Preferably, I would like something which is available as part of JIRA, not that I have to code specifically. I'd assume this problem is quite widestream and it's not just me wishing to have such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app on the Atlassian Marketplace, [Clockwork Automated Timesheets](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219213/clockwork-automated-timesheets?hosting=cloud&tab=overview), that does exactly that.

It fully integrates with Jira's workflow so that the time logged corresponds to how much time an issue was In Progress or had any other active status.

If necessary, the timers can always be started or stopped manually by using Start/Stop buttons.

There are also reports available.

At the moment the app is free.

Cheers,
Jacek